# Move Files of Type from Multiple Directories into a single Directory

Tags: command-line, batch-file, file-transfer, ms-dos

I had a major HDD fail and have recovered the files, but they are spread out over 500 DIRs in a completely random order with no dates

I need to move 10,000 jpgs from 500 DIRs to one DIR, so that I can manually view and sort each file.  Ideally I need to ignore dupes (but not lose them, in case they are in fact different files).

Windows 8 craps out when I try to do this through the desktop search.

What DOS commands should I be using for this?

Comment: forfiles can do what you want: http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move all files of type to a new folder in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/458137/move-all-files-of-type-to-a-new-folder-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my other answer this PowerShell script will gather all files in one folder incrementing count (x) on same names.

```
$BaseDir = 'Q:\Test\2016\'
$Dest    = 'Q:\Test\jpg\'
$Ext     = '.jpg'
$RegEx   = "^(?<Name>.*?) \((?<Cnt>\d+)\)(?<Ext>$([regex]::escape($Ext)))$"

Set-Location $BaseDir

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$Ext" -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = "$Dest$($_.Name)"
    while (Test-Path $NewName){
        If ($NewName -match $RegEx){
            $Cnt = [int]$matches.Cnt +1
            $NewName = "$($matches.Name) ($Cnt)$Ext"
        } Else {
            $NewName = "$Dest$($_.BaseName) (1)$Ext"
        }
    }
    $_|Move-Item -Destination $NewName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would install Everything Search - https://www.voidtools.com/.  That should start you off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your jpg file names look like, but it might be a better choice to see if there are any tags in the files to rename them with date, location whatsoever.

For the copy/move to a single flat folder this batch might help you.
Edit the vars `BaseDir` and `Dest` to suit your environment.
The files are checked with fc.exe if they are real duplicates in which case they are not moved.
If different an explorer like number in parentheses `(1)` is appended.
To have this act on a different extension the var `Ext` may be adapted accordingly.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "BaseDir=Q:\Test\2016\"
Set "Dest=Q:\Test\jpg\"
Set "Ext=.jpg"

Pushd "%BaseDir%"
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /S /A-D *%Ext% 2>Nul' 
) Do If Not Exist "%Dest%%%~nxA" (
  Move "%%~fA" "%Dest%" >Nul
) Else (
  Set Cnt=1
  Call :MoveInc "%%A" "%Dest%%%~nxA"
)
PopD
Goto :EOF

:MoveInc
:: Check if file is a duplicate
Fc.exe /B %1 %2 >Nul 2>&1 && (Echo %1 is a duplicate of %2 &Goto :Eof)
:: Check if name already has (x) appended
Set BaseName=%~n1
Echo %BaseName%|Findstr "([0-9][0-9]*)$" 1>NUL 2>&1 || Goto :Next
:: Get already present number, since " (1)" is at least 4 chars
Set Last=-4

:Again
Echo:!BaseName:~%Last%!|Find " (">NUL||(Set /A Last-=1&Goto :Again) 
Set "BaseName=!BaseName:~0,%Last%!"
Set /A Cnt=!BaseName:~%Last%! +1

:Next
Set "NewName=%Dest%%BaseName% (%Cnt%)%~x1"
If Exist "%NewName%" (Set /A Cnt+=1 & Goto :Next)
Move %1 "%NewName%" >Nul
Goto :Eof
```